# The console.log keeps returning 'Incorrect login' instead of 'Logged in'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I created a login page where if you sign in with your username and password, it world redirect you to another page. In order to test if it is working correctly, I decided to type in the correct username and password I have in my database which would return 'Logged in' in my console.

But every time I hit register, it keeps coming back 'Incorrect login' even though I typed it correctly. I tried fixing it by limiting the data it's selecting in the statement to one but that didn't work as well.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if I didn't type it correctly. What can I do to solve this

this is the backend code in question

```
app.get('/signIn', function (req, res){
  const queryString = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username = ? AND Password  = ? LIMIT 1'
    console.log (req.body)
    con.query(queryString, [req.body.username, req.body.password], function (err, result){
    if (err) {
     throw err;
    }
    if (result.length != 1) {
      return  res.send('Incorrect Login')
    }
    else {
     res.send('Logged In')
    };
    });  
});
```

Edit: I fixed it. `app.get` was supposed to be `app.post`

Comment: Did you debug and look at what result is?

Comment: You're checking if the number of results is not equal to 1. make sure you don't have multiple records in the database with the same username and password. (If you haven't made it already, it's a good practice to make the username column unique)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a typo in your code. In your second `if`, try `result.length !== 1` instead of `result.length != 1`.
If that's not the solution, you might want to do some debugging around con.query() to check what goes on inside of if.